# loading image on a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

First I load an image in a picturebox. Then I measure the areas in it and create a new picture. Now I want to load the image in a panel and draw a line by mouse.
I added to my form:

```
private Image imag;
```

I also added to my project:

```
private void drawP_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = drawP.CreateGraphics(); 
    g.DrawImage(imag, new Point(0,0));
}
```

I set the image in a function:

```
imag = (Image)bm;     
// or
imag = picturebox1.Image; // the made picture   
drawP.Invalidate();
```

But nothing appears when running the project.

Comment: asp.net? silverlight? wpf? winforms? andriod? iOS?

Comment: I'm guessing WinForms by the look of this. @Asma, correct me if I re-tagged it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your code in panel `Paint` event.

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image imag = Image.FromFile(filename);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imag, new Point(0,0)); 
    }
```

This makes you sure that everytime panel is redrawn (after beeing invalidated for any reason) your image is visible.

Comment: I did the changes but again nothing apeared

Comment: @AsmaGood: Are you sure your image `imag` has something inside?

Comment: @AsmaGood: are you sure in your panel you don't have something that covers your image?

Comment: yes, I'm sure.My panel is also emptycan you please write the codes I should use?

Comment: @AsmaGood: take a look at my edited answer. It works, so if you still have problems, they are in a different place...

Comment: First I load the image in a picturebox then I messure the areas in it and make a new image . then I want to load the made image in the panel and then draw sth on it.so I can't load the image directly and use Image.fromfile .when loading the made picture in another picturbox I can see it so I'm sure the problem is not with the made pictre

Comment: @AsmaGood: if you use `pb.Picture = imag;` your edited image is shown correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
private void drawP_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imag, new Point(0,0));
}
```

Also, from your comments, it sounds like you may not have the event wired up.  Example:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  drawP.Paint += drawP_Paint;
}
```

To draw a line on that image:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imag)) {
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(0, 0), new Point(32, 32));
  }
  drawP.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @AsmaGood Obviously it would help me if you told me what the error was, and where in the code.

Comment: It doesn't let me to write "drawP.Paint+=drawP_Paint;" should I add something above my codes like "using System...."?

Comment: @AsmaGood Make sure you have a Panel control named "drawP", make sure you have the drawP_Paint method already in your code.  Just to be sure, you do have your "imag" variable loaded with an image, correct?  Because your posted cost isn't showing you actually have an image.

Comment: I have them all.Thanks alot LarsTech for your attemp.